# Sandy Bridge; or, what's in a name?

Tags: cpu

Nehalem, Atom, Sandy Bridge and Core. Conroe, Wolfdale, Clarkedale and Bloomfield. All processor Architecture and process models (I think, anyway), but where do the names come from? Longhorn was the codename for Vista after a bar in a resort (or so [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_codenames) leads me to believe anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wikipedia page doesn't really explain why Sandy Bridge is named as it is.  It does mention that it was originally named *Gesher*.  What is *Gesher*?  *Gesher* is a Hebrew word (spelled גֶּשֶׁר‎‎ in the Hebrew letters) that means bridge, and has a Hebrew name as it was designed by Intel's Israeli R&D team.

They then changed it because it is also the name of a political party in Israel (long predating the chip, so I don't know why they didn't think of that before they named it), but as an homage to the original name, basically just translated it into English and prepended *Sandy* to further differentiate it from the name of the political party.

In general though, the Oregon R&D team has codenames based off of rivers or occasionally towns in the Pacific Northwest (especially Oregon, but sometimes Washington, such as *Tukwila*), while the Israeli R&D team names it after a river or landmark in Israel.

Comment: Probably the initial code name was approved by engineers who didn't have management levels of paranoia.

Comment: @Dan Sounds like a good theory to me.

Comment: @tombull89, Also note that my answer has to do with _codenames_; Atom and Core are official marketing names.  How their marketing droids come up with names, I do not know.

Answer (score 4):

Just as Microsoft have their page for codenames on Wikipedia, so does [Intel](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/List_of_Intel_codenames).

Comment: sould have looked harder on Wikipedia. Why the https://?

Comment: I use "HTTPS Everywhere". https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere

Comment: +1 for HTTPS everywhere!